# Duplicated header files on pod lib lint: Multiple commands produce ViTempSDK-Swift.h

Tags: cocoapods, xcframework

I'm trying to validate a podspec using pod lib lint but it throws me the error below:

```
/var/folders/bz/s3_w3t2j3l14b7jwfbfc32m40000gp/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20230725-75212-yo2ygu-VitureDeviceSDK/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99. (in target 'ZIPFoundation' from project 'Pods')
/var/folders/bz/s3_w3t2j3l14b7jwfbfc32m40000gp/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20230725-75212-yo2ygu-VitureDeviceSDK/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99. (in target 'iOSDFULibrary' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cyinlyjyloiqciaqiyojesdcymvs/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h' on task: CpHeader /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cyinlyjyloiqciaqiyojesdcymvs/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h /Users/eduardcalero/Documents/Repos/VitureSDK_ForIOS/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/ViTempSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h (in target 'VitureDeviceSDK' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cyinlyjyloiqciaqiyojesdcymvs/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h' on task: CpHeader /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cyinlyjyloiqciaqiyojesdcymvs/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h /Users/eduardcalero/Documents/Repos/VitureSDK_ForIOS/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/ViTempSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h (in target 'VitureDeviceSDK' from project 'Pods')
** BUILD FAILED **
```

This is how the podspec looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'VitureDeviceSDK'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'A short description of VitureDeviceSDK.'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                       DESC

 s.homepage         = 'https://dev.azure.com/vitio/VitureSDK_ForIOS/_git/VitureSDK_ForIOS?path=/VitureDeviceSDK'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Eduard Calero' => 'ecalerorovira@outlook.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://user:***********@dev.azure.com/*****/*****/_git/VitureSDK_ForIOS', :tag => 'VitureDeviceSDK-v1.0.0' }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/EduCalero85'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '15.0'

  s.source_files = 'VitureDeviceSDK/**/*.{h,m,swift,xcframework}'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework'
  #s.preserve_paths = 'VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework' # Solo si se necesita preservar el framework en la ruta de instalación
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework ViTempSDK' }
  
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'SwiftUI'
  
  s.dependency 'iOSDFULibrary', '~> 4.13.0'
  
  # s.resource_bundles = {
  #   'VitureDeviceSDK' => ['VitureDeviceSDK/Assets/*.png']
  # }
  s.public_header_files = 'VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/**/*.h'
  

end
```

(The address of the repo is hidden for security reasons)

This repo has a XCframework (ViTempSDK.xcframework) embedded which is used from the library.

**EDIT**

I've deleted `s.public_header_files = 'VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/**/*.h'`

But the problem persists

```
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h'
        note: Target 'VitureDeviceSDK' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/eduardcalero/Documents/Repos/VitureSDK_ForIOS/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64/ViTempSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h' to '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h'
        note: Target 'VitureDeviceSDK' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/eduardcalero/Documents/Repos/VitureSDK_ForIOS/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/ViTempSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h' to '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h'
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h'
        note: Target 'VitureDeviceSDK' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/eduardcalero/Documents/Repos/VitureSDK_ForIOS/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64/ViTempSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h' to '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h'
        note: Target 'VitureDeviceSDK' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/eduardcalero/Documents/Repos/VitureSDK_ForIOS/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/ViTempSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h' to '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h'
    CreateBuildDirectory /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Intermediates.noindex
        cd /var/folders/bz/s3_w3t2j3l14b7jwfbfc32m40000gp/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20230726-18075-z4d3b9-VitureDeviceSDK
        builtin-create-build-directory /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Intermediates.noindex
    
    CreateBuildDirectory /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products
        cd /var/folders/bz/s3_w3t2j3l14b7jwfbfc32m40000gp/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20230726-18075-z4d3b9-VitureDeviceSDK
        builtin-create-build-directory /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products
    
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h' on task: CpHeader /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h /Users/eduardcalero/Documents/Repos/VitureSDK_ForIOS/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK/Frameworks/ViTempSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/ViTempSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK-Swift.h (in target 'VitureDeviceSDK' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h' on task: CpHeader /Users/eduardcalero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fkjkrcxjdccqtieeghkhmfkomnku/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/VitureDeviceSDK/VitureDeviceSDK.framework/Headers/ViTempSDK.h 
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `s.public_header_files` line. It is only necessary for source CocoaPods. An xcframework specifies public header files via the structure of its various frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply but It looks that is still having the same problem. I don't understand why is duplicating ViTempSDK-Swift.h

Comment: Deleting *.h extension in `  s.source_files = 'VitureDeviceSDK/**/*.{h,m,swift,xcframework}' ` worked for me!